# Coordinates mapping in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack

I apologize if this might be a possible duplicate: I have a field in my csv named `Coordinates` which is of string format like this: `[121.027535, 14.565443]`.

I tried to map it into elasticsearch with `geo-point`, but it says parsing error and all the documents fail to import.

Do I need to preprocess the csv for some conversion beforehand or is the error somewhere else? I am bit new to elasticsearch, so I am not sure how to debug this issue.

Comment: Since Elasticsearch doesn't read CSV, can you tell a bit more about how you're indexing your CSV data?

Comment: I have used the console to put the csv in, the automatic option where it applies the settings itself

Comment: By "console" you mean Kibana ?

Comment: Yes, under `integrations`, I chose the `upload file` option

Comment: Do you mind sharing a few lines of your CSV? maybe via https://gist.github.com

Comment: Yes sure, this is how it looks like:https://gist.github.com/irenehawkins12/991eb15b7d4d3f572e57574bd0d17004

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem is that your Coordinates value is a stringified value (mainly because it contains a comma, which is also the main delimiter).

You can get away with this by creating two columns (`Longitude` and `Latitude`) out of the `Coordinates` one, like this:

```
,RestaurantName,...,Longitude,Latitude
0,Le Petit Souffle,...,121.027535,14.565443
1,Buffet 101,...,120.9796667,14.53133333
2,Vikings,...,120.9793333,14.54
```

Then when you import, you'll have the ability to create a combined field out of them both:

[image]

Comment: I tried doing this but when i upload the csv, it displays `latitude` as keyword and `longitude` as number, so in the combined field option, I don't get anything for latitude.

Comment: it's because you must have a space between the comma and the latitude value, you really need to have it as shown in my example above.

Comment: Yes, I was able to fix it and it works perfectly, thanks alot!